# Postgres connection through airflow DAG

Tags: postgresql, airflow, localhost, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm trying to connect my local Postgres which is running at localhost:5432 with airflow DAG, which is running at  localhost:8080.

I'm sure that Postgres is running at 5432. But in the airflow DAG execution, it is throwing an error that

Error: connection to the server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
Here one more tweak is there, if I'm trying to connect directly by running code in vs code I'm able to connect to postgres and fetch the data.

```
try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "postgres", 
                        user = "postgres", 
                        host= 'localhost',
                        password = "postgres",
                        port = 5432)
        print(conn.closed)
        print("Hola")
```

The same block of code I'm using in both vs code a nd in airflow dag

I've tried the firewall block all the things I found through internet. not able to correct it.

Comment: have you tried localhost without the single quotes

Comment: Error: name 'localhost' is not defined

Comment: Does your airflow under docker? If this the case you need to connect to your  machine local ip and not local host. Localhost from container its the container itself

Comment: I'm not running it under docker, it's using wsl

Comment: Did you try your machine  ip instead of localhost?

Comment: I've tried that as well.. but no use.

postgres running here


 TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7356
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5432         127.0.0.1:58680        ESTABLISHED     7356
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5432         127.0.0.1:58681        ESTABLISHED     7356
  TCP    [::]:5432              [::]:0                 LISTENING       7356